# how to create progress bar in wordpress contact form 7 or other plugin for set progress bar in cf7

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

In wordpress contact form 7 I have try many jquery & plugin to set progress in  cf7

What do you need exactly that WPCF7 can't provide? I've created some custom forms, but all in the context of WPCF7 and I haven't felt the need to actually code the form itself.

what I want? :
 - Change "Select File" to a hyperlink and separate upload button
 - Clicking this should allow user to select the file.
 - Once the file is selected, clicking upload button should upload the file
 - A progress bar should be shown under the field.
 - Once the file is uploaded it should be shown as a hyperlink
 - There should be a X to remove the file.
 - On clicking the submit button after filling the form, the file should be attached as normal in  cf7.

Has anyone done something similar with Contact Form 7?

Anybody could kindly help me to find a quick solution for it? A small hack or something? I just need a progress bar for the upload.

Thanks in Advance